# Find duplicate array values and delete conditionally

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an multidimensional array like this:

```
$orders = array(
  array(
    'id' => '123',
    'name' => 'John',
    'lastname'=>'Carter',
    'rate' => '1.0'
  ),
  array(
    'id' => '546',
    'name' => 'Ben',
    'lastname'=>'Wall',
    'rate' => '0.25'
  ),
  array(
    'id' => '666',
    'name' => 'John Bow',
    'lastname'=>'Porter',
    'rate' => '0.25'
  ),
  array(
    'id' => '156',
    'name' => 'John',
    'lastname'=>'Carter',
    'rate' => '0.5'
  )
);
```

and want make a function that will be delete duplicate rows that rate < 1.0. The result array should be:

```
$orders = array(
  array(
    'id' => '123',
    'name' => 'John',
    'lastname'=>'Carter',
    'rate' => '1.0'
  ),
  array(
    'id' => '546',
    'name' => 'Ben',
    'lastname'=>'Wall',
    'rate' => '0.25'
  ),
  array(
    'id' => '666',
    'name' => 'John',
    'lastname'=>'Porter',
    'rate' => '0.25'
  )
);
```

Comment: tried kill duplicating rows in array. The row is duplicate if it has the same value in 'name' and 'lastname'.

Answer (score 0):

### Edit: Second and good version here: http://ideone.com/zJ8vj

---

What do You mean by 'duplicated' - same 'rate' ?
Bellow example remove duplicated orders with same 'rate' and 'rate' < 1.0.
Is this what You need ?

```
$tmpOrders = array();
foreach($orders as $order) {
    // Check only rate < 1.0
    if((float)$order['rate'] < 1.0) {
        // Check duplicate
        $exists = false;
        foreach($tmpOrders as $tmp) {
            if($tmp['rate'] == $order['rate']) {
                $exists = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        // Add if rate not exists
        if(!$exists) {
            $tmpOrders[] = $order;
        }
    }
    // Add all with rate >= 1.0
    else {
        $tmpOrders[] = $order;
    }
}
$orders = $tmpOrders;

echo "<pre>";
print_r($orders);
echo "<pre>";
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 123
            [name] => John
            [lastname] => Carter
            [rate] => 1.0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 546
            [name] => Ben
            [lastname] => Wall
            [rate] => 0.25
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 156
            [name] => John
            [lastname] => Carter
            [rate] => 0.5
        )

)
```

Comment: thanks for comment. In your result [0] and [2] element are duplicate, because the 'name' and 'lastname' equal. And need delete [2] element, because 'rate' of [2] element < 1.0

Comment: OK, second version: Add all elements with rate >= 1.0, then add only no duplicates. http://ideone.com/zJ8vj

Answer (score 0):

Not very beautiful and speed, but workable solution:

```
$a = array(...); // Your array

$hashstack = array_map(function($value) { return md5($value['name'] . $value['lastname']); }, $a);
$result = array_filter($a, function($value) use ($hashstack)
{
    if ((float)$value['rate'] < 1.0) {
        $count = 0;
        foreach ($hashstack as $hash) {
            if (md5($value['name'] . $value['lastname']) == $hash) {
                $count++;
            }
        }
        if ($count > 1) {
            unset($value);
            return;
        }
    }
    return $value;
});
```

Result is the same of yours.